# Apply function to combine one cell with the each element in the vector from the other cell in the same row

Tags: r

I have a following dataframe:

```
**seq**                                    **link**
c(0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120)             http://website_1.com/
0                                          http://website_2.com/
c(0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120, 140, 160)   http://website_3.com/ 
c(0, 20)                                   http://website_4.com/
```

I want to combine the link with each element in the vector at the same row so I would have a dataframe:

```
http://website_1.com/0
http://website_1.com/20
http://website_1.com/40
```

etc.

I tried this code but it didn't work

```
for (i in a$seq) {
  link = paste0(a$link, i)
  print(link)
        }
```

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `tidyverse` packages `tidyr`, `dplyr` and `purrr`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

sequence  <-  list(seq(0,120,20), 0, seq(0,160,20), seq(0,20, 20))
links <- c("http://website_1.com/", "http://website_2.com/", "http://website_3.com/", "http://website_4.com/")

tibble(sequence, links) %>% 
  mutate(completed_links = map2(links, sequence, paste0)) %>% 
  unnest()

# A tibble: 19 × 3
                   links sequence          completed_links
                   <chr>    <dbl>                    <chr>
1  http://website_1.com/        0   http://website_1.com/0
2  http://website_1.com/       20  http://website_1.com/20
3  http://website_1.com/       40  http://website_1.com/40
4  http://website_1.com/       60  http://website_1.com/60
5  http://website_1.com/       80  http://website_1.com/80
6  http://website_1.com/      100 http://website_1.com/100
7  http://website_1.com/      120 http://website_1.com/120
8  http://website_2.com/        0   http://website_2.com/0
9  http://website_3.com/        0   http://website_3.com/0
10 http://website_3.com/       20  http://website_3.com/20
11 http://website_3.com/       40  http://website_3.com/40
12 http://website_3.com/       60  http://website_3.com/60
13 http://website_3.com/       80  http://website_3.com/80
14 http://website_3.com/      100 http://website_3.com/100
15 http://website_3.com/      120 http://website_3.com/120
16 http://website_3.com/      140 http://website_3.com/140
17 http://website_3.com/      160 http://website_3.com/160
18 http://website_4.com/        0   http://website_4.com/0
19 http://website_4.com/       20  http://website_4.com/20
```

What the code does is:

1. Place your sequences and links into a `tibble` specialized data frame.
2. Use `mutate` to create a new variable, completed links.
3. Inside the mutate, we use `map2` to create a separate complete link for each link and number in your sequence using `paste0` (`map2` iterates a function over 2 variables provided to it).
4. `unnest` at the end to put everything into it's own row instead of lists within columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

a <- tribble(
~seq,                              ~link,
  c(0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120),             "http://website_1.com/",
  0          ,                                "http://website_2.com/",
  c(0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120, 140, 160) ,  "http://website_3.com/", 
  c(0, 20)                             ,      "http://website_4.com/")

unnest(a) %>% mutate(newlink=paste0(link, seq))
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with this data set.

```
dat
                  links                              sequence
1 http://website_1.com/           0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120
2 http://website_2.com/                                     0
3 http://website_3.com/ 0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120, 140, 160
4 http://website_4.com/                                 0, 20
```

In base, R you could use `Map` and `unlist` to return a vector of the desired output and then put that into a data.frame if desired with `data.frame`.

```
unlist(Map(paste0, dat[[1]], dat[[2]])
```

will return the desired result as a vector and

```
data.frame(linkSeq=unlist(Map(paste0, dat[[1]], dat[[2]]))
```

will return the result as a data.frame.

**data**

```
dat <- data.frame(links=c("http://website_1.com/", "http://website_2.com/",
                          "http://website_3.com/", "http://website_4.com/"))
dat$sequence <- list(seq(0,120,20), 0, seq(0,160,20), seq(0,20, 20))
```